# How to copy all properties of a textblock to another textblock in c#?

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I have a textblock visual_name defined in Grid(xaml) which is used as visual cue for programatically adding the textblock to a Grid

How can I copy all Properties of visual_name to  programmatically created textblock(txtblock) ?

```
 <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">


    <TextBlock x:Name="visual_name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.419,0.528" Margin="84,187,0,0" Width="220" Foreground="#FF0E0E0E"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="visual_point" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="352,187,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="102" Height="28" Foreground="Black"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="visual_rank" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,186,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="56" Height="28">

    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

My C# Code:

```
   foreach(Leaders leader in listofleaders )
           {
               TextBlock txtblock = new TextBlock();
              //copy properties of visual_name  to txtblock
               txtblock.Text = leader.name;
               // add margin
               LayoutRoot.Children.Add(txtblock);
           }
```

Comment: `visual_name` will just be an object,  if you want an EXACT copy of that object,  there is no reason you shouldn't be able to go `txtblock = visual_name;`

Comment: @Nikerym txtblock=visual_name threw error 'Element is already the child of another element.'

Comment: that's because your copying the object,   i think you mean clone?   you need to create a NEW copy of the object,  not an exact copy.  in that case it's a bit more complex.  In which case go with @Dev-Sharma's Answer below.

Comment: It is better to use some ItemsControl for that. ListBox with custom panel for ex

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to clone your Textblock object. Maybe you can try `XamlWriter` in `System.Windows.Markup` namespace.

Probably below code can help.

Write textblock in xaml and get a string in return.

```
string visualNameXaml = XamlWriter.Save(visual_name);
```

And then you can retrieve by using below code.

```
StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(visualNameXaml);
XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
TextBlock newTextBlock = (TextBlock)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
```

After doing that you can add the textblock dynamically.
Hope this helps!.

Comment: there is no Xamlwriter class. i'm on silverlight windows phone project. any way thanks for answer